# How set multiple env variables for a bash command

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

I am supposed to set the EC2_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables
before running a command (ec2-describe-regions)

How do I do that in one go?

Answer (score 274):

You can one-time set vars for a single command by putting them on the command line before the command:

```
$ EC2_HOME=/path/to/dir JAVA_HOME=/other/path ec2-describe-regions
```

Alternately, you can export them in the environment, in which case they'll be set for all future commands:

```
$ export EC2_HOME=/path/to/dir
$ export JAVA_HOME=/other/path
$ ec2-describe-regions
```

Comment: Note that, although it seems uncommon, you can also write `export EC2_HOME=/path JAVA_HOME=/path`.

Comment: The one-time option is quite useful in scripts. Just a note for anyone who needs to execute the command as root or another user, the variables should come *after* sudo or the user. For example `sudo -u somebody CVSROOT=:ext:somebody@12.18.127.22:/usr/local/ncvs CVS_RSH=ssh cvs co my/dir/ancient-file.py`

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of variables you can supply via prepending?

Comment: Just the maximum command line length limit, which is quite large on linux.

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to use one variable in the definition of another. Something like `A=Foo B=$A$A echo $B`? It doesn't seem to work as a one-liner, though. It could be convenient for JAVA_HOME and PATH, for example.

Comment: @EricDuminil All of these assignments apply only to the environment of the command being run, not to the environment of the shell.  All the $X references in the input will be expanded by the shell (not the command) so cannot possibly be affected by them.  In order to have an assignment affect a use, the use would have to be in the command (possible using an `eval` though quoting is tricky:  `A=Foo eval 'B=$A$A eval '"'"'echo $B'"'"`)

Answer (score 92):

If you want to use the environment variables multiple times in the same session you can use:

```
export VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 VARN=valueN
```

If you want to execute a command with multiple variables without affecting the current bash session, you can use:

```
VAR1=value1 VAR2=value2 VARN=valueN command arg=1
```

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
sh -c "VAR1=BLA-BLA VAR2=FOO-BAR && command"
```

E.g.:

```
sh -c "VAR1=BLA-BLA VAR2=FOO-BAR && exec echo $VAR1 $VAR2"
```

Output:

```
BLA-BLA FOO-BAR
```

**Notice**: run command via `exec` to terminate whole `sh` process after command finishing.

Answer (score 4):

As other *nix system, you can add function as following in your .bashrc file under your HOME directory.

```
function startec2(){
    export EC2_HOME=/path/to/dir
    export JAVA_HOME=/other/path 
    ec2-describe-regions
}
```

Now, you can start your program by the following command:

```
startec2
```

Comment: This would make the variables to persist even after the function has been called. In particular with such a cover function, I would make sure that the environment is only modified for that command execution also, and I would honour explicit environment settings which the caller might have been done before calling your function.  Hence I would write i.e. `EC2_HOME=${EC2_HOME:-/path/to/dir} JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME:-/other/path ec2-describe-regions`