# How to set multiple enviroment variable in django-crontab ?Ac

Tags: python, django

According to this document https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/

If I want to set a variable environment in crontab, I should do this

```
CRONTAB_COMMAND_PREFIX="STAGE=production"
```

provided I want to set multiple variables, what should I do ?

I tried

```
CRONTAB_COMMAND_PREFIX="STAGE=production,TOKEN=ABC"
```

but seems to be not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ENV`s [should be separated by space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272557/13946204).

So correct usage will be `CRONTAB_COMMAND_PREFIX="STAGE=production TOKEN=ABC"`

After that `django-crontab` will [join](https://github.com/kraiz/django-crontab/blob/978a26d547f1004ee286d08e31625bfbcee28811/django_crontab/crontab.py#L91) prefix with command line and it will be looks like

```bash
STAGE=production TOKEN=ABC command
```